# pandas bar chart y-axis min max range in floating number

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

[image: bar chart]

I have a graph like this. I want to build it using python matplotlib.pyplot. However I get the graph like this.

[image]

How can I change the range of y-axis? instead of 0 to 13, I want it to range from min_value-1 to max_value+1 in floating values.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?
Just a simple example.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

array = np.array([110,200,300])
ax = plt.gca()

minimum = array.min()-10
maximum = array.max()+10
ax.set_ylim([minimum,maximum])
plt.bar(range(len(array)), array)
```